# Using Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, version-control, client

What is the simplest (to install and use) git client for Windows nowadays?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/) and [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) / [GitCheetah](http://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/GitCheetah)

Comment: I'm a long time user of TortoiseSVN, will I get the same/similar user experience (aka/ smaller learning curve) if I choose TortoiseGit?

Comment: I had heaps of problems with SSH+msygit. IMHO do yourself a favour and just use Cygwin.

Comment: The whole po9int of TortoiseGit is to provide the same level of convenience and a similar environment for people used to TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 6):

Apart from others have already said, there is also [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html).

Comment: @Kuroki, if I understand correctly, it's actually git which has problems with Unicode characters in filenames (on Windows).

Comment: [SmartGit requires JRE](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download.html?all=true) and isn't open source. On the other hand, it has a portable version from which you can remove the JRE, and it's free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 5):

[msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/wiki/InstallMSysGit) is, like everyone else said, wonderful.

You should also look into [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) for visual studio integration, which I find I can't live without.

Answer (score 2):

I just use the one in Cygwin, although many people are looking forward to [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) once its out of the preview stage. If they make it a no-brainer to install (like in Cygwin), it would be nice.

Comment: I've tried that one before, it's a pain in the ass to setup. I want something that's quick and easy to deploy.

Comment: Which one? I mentioned two. I think cygwin is amazingly easy to install.

Answer (score 1):

I had serious issues with negotiating SSL connections with msygit+putty. It's so much easier on cygwin. I even wrote up a guide on it. See [Windows Git Tutorial: Cygwin, SSH and Projectlocker](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/09/windows-git-tutorial-cygwin-ssh-and.html).

Comment: Why not use native SSH? Much easier. I just placed .ssh folder in my user directory and never worried about it. Of course it has to be a passwordless key in order not to type the password in all the time.